# Syntax error in EXTRACT() query, what operator is missing?

Tags: sql, function, ms-access, syntax-error

I have a table in MS Access that tracks when members of our pool check in with their pool pass that looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to generate a report that displays the data so I can see how many 'Check-Ins' we've had for each year of operation like so:

```
Season   Visits
2021     432
2020     123
2019     354
etc.
```

My plan is to extract the year from the CHECKINTIME, then count the number of unique ID's in that year.
I'm using the following SQL for my query:

```
SELECT 
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM tblCheckIn.[CHECKINTIME]) AS Season,
  COUNT(tblCheckIn.[ID]) AS Visits
FROM tblCheckIn
GROUP BY (YEAR FROM tblCheckIn.[CHECKINTIME]);
```

Right now I'm getting the following error: `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'EXTRACT(YEAR FROM tblCheckIn.[CHECKINTIME])` I've been pouring over the documentation for `EXTRACT()` but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm guessing it's specifically an MS Access thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ms Access uses a `YEAR` function and not extract

```
SELECT 
  YEAR(tblCheckIn.[CHECKINTIME]) AS Season,
  COUNT(tblCheckIn.[ID]) AS Visits
FROM tblCheckIn
GROUP BY YEAR(tblCheckIn.[CHECKINTIME]);
```

or you can use

```
SELECT DatePart("yyyy",tblCheckIn.[CHECKINTIME]) AS NewDate FROM tblCheckIn;
```

Comment: LAHHHH!!! (Songs of Angels) Thank you!!